# NSArray redefinition with a different type int & missing type specifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

The following code will not build and provides the warning of "Type specifier missing, defaults to 'int'" and the error "Redefinition of 'my_var' with a different type: 'int' vs 'NS Array *__strong'.

```
NSArray *my_var = nil;
my_var = @[
  @[@312, @"Name1"],
  @[@313, @"Name2"]
];
```

What am I missing?  I've tried many different refactorings and for some reason cannot compile with a pre-defined `NSArray`.

Comment: where do you "predefine" it?

Comment: @vikingosegundo In the code above.  I meant it is not created and populated at run-time, but is a static array available at build time.

Comment: again: where in your source code do you "predefine" it?

Comment: I created an empty file, named it `regions.h` and then import it into a view's .m file.

Comment: man, show the code. if you have this in regios.h it is wrong.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem... this *is* the code.  If that's wrong, then I may have asked the wrong question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put that code at global or file scope, outside of any function or method definition.  You can't do that.  The second assignment to `my_var` is only valid inside a function or method body.  Outside of a function/method body, the compiler thinks the second line is another variable declaration, with a (default) type of `int`.

You can't initialize `my_var` to an `NSArray` literal statically.  A `NSArray` literal is different than a literal `NSString`.  A literal `NSString` is created by the compiler and stored, fully usable, in the executable file.  An `NSArray` literal turns into code that calls methods at runtime (under the covers) to create the array.  That code is only allowed inside a function or method body.

If you want a global constant `NSArray`, use a global function that creates the array once and returns it every time.  Declare it in a `.h` file like this:

```
NSArray *my_var();
```

And define it in a `.m` file like this:

```
NSArray *my_var() {
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static NSArray *array;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^{
        array = @[
            @[@312, @"Name1"],
            @[@313, @"Name2"]
        ];
    });
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I bet that is it!  Going to test now.  That must have been what viking was alluding to.

Comment: Updated with more information and a suggested solution.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you.  I'd have never figured this out b/c I didn't even know what context I should have been looking at.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want the objects of your array to be dictionary objects:

So why not try:

```
NSArray *my_var = @[ 
    @{ @"Name1" : @312 },
    @{ @"Name2" : @313 },
];
```

Comment: most likely it should be on dictionary. or the keys should be equal.